# Disallow users to change account record type

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to create a validation rule that should disallow users from changing an account record type with the exception of the system admin.

This is what I have written:

```
    AND ( NOT($Profile.Name!='System Administrator'), 
    IsChanged(RecordTypeId))
```

When I remove the NOT, then I cannot change the record type as a system admin, so I added the NOT, but now I can always change the record type. What do I need to change?
Tia, Lily.

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the record type from the Page Layouts, change it to Read-Only or edit profile settings so that it isn't editable?

Comment: No, the record type field needs to be visible

Comment: You could also create a formula field that gets the record type name, and display only that.

Comment: Record Type does not seem to be available in a formula field

Comment: Do you want system admin's to need access to change record type. @Lily

Answer (score 1):

You can try this formula in the validation rule

```
AND(ISCHANGED(RecordTypeId), 
NOT( $Profile.Name = "System Administrator"))
```

The usage of != inside NOT makes it =, so its throwing error even for System Administrators.

Hope it helps.